# Can I safely use unicode characters (e.g. accents) in CSS class names or ids?

Tags: css

I just encountered a situation where product names are automatically pulled in to my HTML as class names, and one of those product names has an accented letter.  It looks like this:

```
<div class="español">Hola</div>
```

If I add a CSS declaration with that class, like this:

```
.español {background:yellow;}
```

Will it cause any problems?  It seems to work so far, but I'm not sure if it's completely cross-browser compatible.

Also, would it be any different if that were an id instead of a class?  That seems to work so far, too, but again I am not sure if it'll hold up everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What characters are valid in CSS class selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Comment: Even if you *can*, I would avoid putting non-ascii characters in any class/variable names. It seems like something that has the potential to cause grief in the future.

Comment: @tom - yeah, that's what I was concerned about, but I was hoping for someone to prove me wrong so that I wouldn't have to change the whole automated class name system here.

Comment: @Pekka - yeah, I did see that other question, but it was asked nearly 5 years ago, and things change.

Comment: They don't really change that much. All the info here is also available in the duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently yes. In fact, HTML 4.01 already allowed you to use Unicode characters in the [`class`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-class) attribute. Now HTML 5 allows them also on the [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-id) attribute. The cool thing is that it's been tested with IE 6 and works too, so it's backwards compatible.

Now what you should ask yourself is, do I *really* need them? In my eyes is just asking for trouble because while the W3 accepts them, some not-major browser might not support them (think browsers for the visually impaired or others).

Read this for more info on the subject: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class.

Answer (score 14):

From the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> "In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_)"

The ISO 10646 standard and Unicode standard have synchronised their character sets ([ref](http://www.unicode.org/faq/unicode_iso.html)), so in this aspect they are the same.

[The ñ character has the character code U+00F1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm), so that is safe to use in an identifier.